# Does feature size affect polynomial regression?

Tags: regression, python, normalization, feature-engineering, polynomial

By ***feature size***, I mean the value of the numbers.

For example, let's say I have input `X = [[0],[1],[2],[4]]` and output `y = [4,1,2,5]` (left plot). I then multply each element by a *million* (right plot):

[image: Input and output]

That looks the same, just on a different scale, great.

Now if I fit a polynomial regression model with degree 4 to both sets of data, shouldn't I get the same looking polynomial?

I get this strange thing (on the right):
[image: Fitted]

Or, zoomed out for the right plot:

[image: Zoomed out]

I'm doing something very wrong, aren't I?

---

This is the python code I generated these plots with:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline

# Creating the model I'm going to use for fitting both sets of data 
model = make_pipeline(PolynomialFeatures(degree=4), LinearRegression())

# The little numbers data
X = sp.array([[0],[1],[2],[4]])
y = sp.array([4, 1, 2, 5])

model.fit(X, y);

# Plotting
ax = plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
allXs = np.linspace(min(X), max(X), 100)
plt.plot(allXs[:,np.newaxis], model.predict(allXs[:, np.newaxis]))
plt.scatter(X, y)


# The above data just multiplied by one million
X = [x*1000000 for x in X]
y = [x*1000000 for x in y]

model.fit(X, y);

# Plotting
bx = plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.ylim(0, 6000000)
allXs = np.linspace(min(X), max(X), 100)
plt.plot(allXs[:,np.newaxis], model.predict(allXs[:, np.newaxis]))
plt.scatter(X, y)

plt.show()
```

Comment: *Something* has certainly gone wrong. I'm not going to check your code, but high order polynomial regression can be ill-conditioned. For large $x$, $x^{k+1}$ is almost a linear function of $x^{k}$ and lower order terms.

Comment: Could you please update your code so it can run? For example, you never define newaxis and don't import numpy, scipy, or matplotlib.pyplot.

Comment: @JasonSanchez - Ah, sorry. Updated.

Comment: @Glen_b - Is scaling down the right way to go then? Where could I read more about this?

Thank you very much for your time, guys.

Comment: Centering and scaling will help up to a point and might be sufficient. I *wouldn't* say it's "the right way to go". If you must use polynomial regression, I'd say orthogonal polynomials would be "the right way to go", but you may not need to do that to get suitable estimates; centering and scaling may get you there. On the other hand, if polynomial regression isn't a requirement for you, you might consider natural cubic regression splines, smoothing splines, or a number of other ways of fitting smooth models.

Comment: The condition number of X is the ratio of largest to smallest eigenvalue.If you rescale by a million, then I would expect your condition number to scale by at least 10^(6*3)